# Extracting temperature from Global Land Data Assimilation System (GLDAS) netcdf4 file using python?

Tags: python, hdf5, netcdf, netcdf4

I extract temperature data from the netcdf4 file using python I used these code but it returns only null values.

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset

nc = Dataset("GLDAS_NOAH025_3H.A20170102.0000.021.nc4","r")
for temp in nc.variables['AvgSurfT_inst'] :
    print (temp)
```

Output:

```
[[[-- -- -- ..., -- -- --]
  [-- -- -- ..., -- -- --]
  [-- -- -- ..., -- -- --]
  ..., 
  [-- -- -- ..., -- -- --]
  [-- -- -- ..., -- -- --]
  [-- -- -- ..., -- -- --]]]
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, there is not a question in this post.

Comment: If you point the location of the original file, someone may be able to confirm if there is any unmasked data in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily check if all / how much values are masked (missing) by counting the amount of masked values with `np.ma.count_masked(data)`. As an example, for a random NetCDF file:

```
import numpy as np
import netCDF4 as nc4

f = nc4.Dataset('bomex.ql.0000000.nc')

for v in f.variables:
    arr = f.variables[v][:]
    print('{0:}: values = {1:}, masked_values = {2:}'.format(v, np.size(arr), np.ma.count_masked(arr)))
```

Which gives me something like:

> z: values = 32, masked_values = 0
>
> zh: values = 33, masked_values = 0
>
> u: values = 416, masked_values = 362
>
> v: values = 416, masked_values = 362
>
> w: values = 429, masked_values = 369